# python selenium driver.switch_to.frame() suddenly failed at the second time to locate the same frame

Tags: python, selenium

I have composed a mini program of selenium to automate something.
at the first time, below code is running perfect:

```
driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
driver.switch_to.frame('content01')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ckzx"]/div[7]/a').click()
time.sleep(0.5)
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(handle)
    if "return task" in driver.title:
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)
        task_window = driver.current_window_handle
        print('task_window')
        print(task_window)
        break

driver.switch_to.frame("leftFrame")
return_tasks = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('return tasks')
```

then I add some tasks into the task_window. Which the tasks can be manipulated in the 'leftFrame'. But it failed at the second time:

```
driver.switch_to.window(task_window)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame('leftFrame')  ### failed at this line
```

And the ERROR info is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Py\2_d\2_d.py", line 719, in <module>
driver.switch_to.frame('leftFrame')   ## failed at this line
   File "C:\Users\louis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 82, in frame
      frame_reference = self._driver.find_element(By.ID, frame_reference)
    File "C:\Users\louis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-      packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
      return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    File "C:\Users\louis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
      self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "C:\Users\louis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-      packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
      raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving       message from renderer: 300.000
    (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)
```

Background: the failure occurs suddenly, which I mean is it's normal several days before, then, suddenly, someday, it occurs, and never gone. I don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

You need to switch to default content first before switching to the left frame.

**Code:**

```
driver.switch_to.window(task_window)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(5)

driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.switch_to.frame('leftFrame')
```

the reason behind that is that you are already in `content01` frame and driver has focused on it so in order to switch to left frame it should set to default content and then switch.

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey, I have tried the "driver.switch_to.parent.frame()", then after your answer, I followed your instructions. But it still failed here. It seems we've get to this window handle, but we can not get to the frame. The page HTML structure is three frames under a frameset.

Comment: I even used this:      try:
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        print('markerror20220315-4-1')
    except:
        driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
        print('markerror20220315-4-2')   but also stucked before these sentences.

Comment: What are your manual steps? like you open a window (parent window, by default launch by Selenium) and you switch to `content01` and then you open a new window either through JS call and in the new window you want to switch to frame?

Comment: Nice to have you noticed my comments.  If I do it manually, there are 2 window, I pick tasks in the main window, then it will stored into the task window.  The sentence switch_to.window is ok, but any after this line is not work, include driver,title, page_source, switch_to.frame, default.content, all will come to the timeout result.

Comment: Hello, @cruisepandey,  I finally found the reason: the website suddenly use the Trident core instead of default blink core. IE = Trident? when it's in this mode, the window is not responding, till timeout.